# Why does python shell only execute first line?

Tags: python, python-idle

Why does python shell (IDLE) only execute first line? I'm just doing a simple print 'hello world' on one line and then print 'my world' on a second line. Pressing enter only returns "hello world"

Code

```
print 'Hello world!'
print 'My world!'
```

---

Results

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: How did you run this?  If this script is in a file, did you make sure to save it before you run it?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you're entering these commands in the shell?

Comment: If you are running those commands in Python 3.x you would get a syntax error after your first statement.

Comment: I can reproduce this on my machine - copy the multiline string into IDLE, and push enter - only the first line is executed. Closing as off topic - this is really a bug report.

Comment: Interesting how it would capitalize your `w`...

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.3. I typed the first line of code then pressed control j to go to another line, then typed the second line of code and then pressed ENTER. The output was only the first line.

Comment: @JoseRodriguez -- I added the fact that you're using `IDLE` to the post.  That seems to be an important part of the question.

Comment: "if you're not using ipython, you're doing it wrong" :)